# Distributable JAR not working

Tags: java, executable-jar

I created a project in Netbeans 7.1 on my netbook which uses Windows XP. I used the Clean and Build command which created the distributable JAR file in the /dist folder. When I double clicked the file it worked.

Now I sent the entire project folder to my desktop, which uses Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit. When I double clicked the executable JAR I got an error saying:
*Could Not find or load main class myapp.jar*

I checked the manifest file and it contains the main class name. Of course, it was autogenerated by Netbeans.

What is going on?

Comment: Try running it from the command line using java -jar myapp.jar and understand what the error message and stack trace says.

Comment: The bit after `Could Not find or load main class..` usually shows the fully qualified class name of the main class.  Why does your message follow that with the name of the Jar (`..myapp.jar`)?  1) If you mis-typed that, the advice would be "Always copy/paste error messages". 2) If the manifest actually states the main-class as `myapp.jar` - change it.

Comment: Ok I tried this command and it appears I had forgotten to copy a DLL file. It works now. thanks!
However, I have a new problem. The API i am using is JIntellitype. Its readme says that I need to either copy the DLL file to system32 folder or need to add it to classpath. It works when i copy it to system32. But not working when I only add it to classpath environment variable. WHY?

Comment: A DLL is not searched in the CLASSPATH. It's searched in the PATH.

Comment: I tried putting it in PATH but still did not work. Then I deleted the DLL from my system32 folder on my netbook, put it into the project folder and CLEAN & BUILD again. It worked fine on my netbook but again not working on my desktop.

Comment: I added the DLL to the /dist path and now the application works, albeit with some errors which I feel are related to something else. Anyhow, I m still stumped as to why adding to PATH doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

The common mistake is to forget to also take the "layout" folder. If you have used specific features of Netbeans, such as bindings, in the "dist" you have the jar but also a folder with the name "layout" in it and you must also copy it with the jar file and put it at the same target place.

In my case it was a pity having to also send this folder so I decided to stop using binding and other specific stuff and used to reprogram things by hand. Now I only send the jar and it is working.

Note that you can easily know if you have specific features.
Open Netbeans and look in your project folder. There you'll have 2 folder, "Source Packages" and "libraries". Check in libraries. If you have only the JDK it is ok. If you have other libraries listed, then there will be the supplementary folder in the dist and you will have to send it with the Jar.

Hope it helps

Comment: yes i do have other stuff in libraries. But I am also sending them to me desktop. Like I said, I am copying the ENTIRE project folder to my desktop.

Comment: Ok I was not sure you were "really" copying all the folder. So my answer is quite useless for you but I let it as it can help some other people. In your case I've seen you have found the solution by putting the dll in the correct place.